# I got an "import beyond top-level package" when trying to import tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a Raspbian freshly installed on my RBPi 3. I've installed Tenorflow using pip3 (version: tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl), but when I tried to import it (from python IDLE 3 shiped with Raspbian) I got this error :

```
from .....third_party import wrapt
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I got the same error when trying to import Keras, but presumably it's because it failed to import TF in the first place.

These are the packages I successfully installed and imported beforhand:

```
Cpython scipy scikit-learn pandas matplotlib
```

Note: I didn't setup a virtualenv, working directly on parent path: home/pi

EDIT:
The Full traceback

```
>>> import tensorflow
/home/pi/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/pi/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/pi/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/pi/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/pi/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/pi/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.4 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.5
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 432, got 412
  return f(*args, **kwds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/data_structures.py", line 27, in <module>
    import wrapt
ImportError: No module named 'wrapt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.standard_ops import *
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/ops/standard_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import autograph
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/autograph/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph import operators
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.operators.control_flow import for_stmt
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops import scan_ops
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/data/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data import experimental
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.batching import dense_to_sparse_batch
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/batching.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.ops import dataset_ops
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 67, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training.tracking import tracking
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/tracking.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training.tracking import data_structures
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/data_structures.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .....third_party import wrapt
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?

Comment: Sure, I've added it.

Comment: How exactly did you install tensorflow? It does not look like a standard installation

Comment: I downloded  TF pckg from GitHub
wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v1.8.0/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
Then I used Pip3 to install it:
pip3 install tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl

Comment: If you installed with pip then you should not have a folder called tensorflow in your home folder, its probably interferring with your tensorflow installation

Comment: Huge thanks, SOLVED.
As you mentioned,that {home/pi/tensorflow} was the causing troubles, seems like it was there from previous attempts to install a compatible version of TF on RP, once I deleted that folder, the problem gone. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by @[Matias Valdenegro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/matias-valdenegro)

> If you installed with pip then you should not have a folder called
>   tensorflow in your home folder, its probably interferring with your
>   tensorflow installation

I deleted that tensorflow folder from home folder, as  @[Matias Valdenegro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/matias-valdenegro) mentioned, it was interfering with the standard installation, I deleted it, and it resolved.

I suggest that on each attempt to install Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi, incomplete/unsuccessful attempts should be carefully cleaned up.